# Почему не ставится запятая после ДА ВОН?

Tags: пунктуация, частица, поэзия, междометие

В одном из заданий на сайте *Решу ЕГЭ* просят расставить запятые в стихотворении:

```
По тропке, опершись на подожок,
Идет старик, сметая пыль с бурьяна.
"Прохожий!
Укажи, дружок,
Где тут живет Есенина Татьяна?"

"Татьяна...  Гм...
Да вон за той избой.
А ты ей что?
Сродни?
Аль, может, сын пропащий?"
```

Здесь приведено верное написание. Однако у меня возник вопрос по поводу отсутствующей запятой после **да вон**. Почему она здесь не ставится? К слову, я прочитал именно с паузой в этом месте, словно это уточнение: "Да вон *там* (пауза) за той избой".

В *Нацкорпусе*, к примеру, есть такие предложения:

> ― Да вон там, за камнями, видишь, без сапог? [И. М. Дьяконов. Книга
>   воспоминаний. Часть вторая. Глава четвертая]
>
> В каком направлении? ― Да вон, через лес. Ещё не всё понимая, Костя не
>   спеша пошёл по меже в сторону леса. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]

И последний вопрос: какой частью речи является слово *вон* в этом стихотворении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**ВОН**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-academ-term-8859.htm) (2) частица, *разг.*
1. Употребляется для указания на какой-либо предмет, находящийся в отдалении.
*— Вон одна звездочка, вон другая, вон третья: как много! — говорила Марфенька, глядя на небо.* И. Гончаров, Обрыв.
2. В сочетании с указательными и относительными местоимениями и наречиями имеет значение уточнения.
*Вон туда надо идти.*

[**ДА**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?all=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%B0) 1. Частица.
8. (в начале предл. или внутри его перед сказ., группой сказ.) Употр. для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности.
*Да так оно обычно и бывает. Куда идти? — Да прямо!*

Да вон за той избой — говорящий как будто отмахивается, указывая только общее направление, не уточняя, за какой именно избой.

Да вон там, за той избой; *Вон там, за последним холмом, ее дом* — эти конструкции имеют значение уточнения, поэтому обособляются.

*Подъезжаем! Видишь, вон за той рекой моя деревня, вон она, там, на холме, вся в садах утопает* (Ф. Иванов. За старой стеной).

*Но пообедать всё равно надо, так что давайте, вон за той сопкой у ручья и перекусим* (Ю. Запевалов. Золото севера).

Answer (score 1):

**И последний вопрос: какой частью речи является слово вон в этом стихотворении?**

Местоименное наречие. Словарь Ожегова говорит:

> **ВОН**(2) (разг.). 1. мест. нареч. Указывает на  происходящее или
>   находящееся в нек-ром  отдалении. *В. он идёт. В. туда иди.*

Постановка запятой в данном случае зависит от того, имел в виду автор уточнение направления в словах "за той избой" или указание на само направление.

Приведу пару примеров.

> А вон за мысом, на ближнем пустоплесье! (В. Бианки)
>
> Вон, за тем огородом, видишь? (Г.П. Данилевский)

И напоследок простой совет: для того чтобы правильно расставлять знаки препинания в стихотворениях, желательно их запоминать с правильной интонацией :)